# Finding the frequency of object key VALUES in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have an array of objects (police data, each one is a crime). The array of objects is 1000 in length.

Every object has a key/value such as `community_area: 22`.

I am trying to iterate over the array of objects to find the top three community areas that exist in the array. So if community areas 22, 70 and 1 had the most crime (each object occurrence) it would return those three.

What is an efficient way of doing this other than creating arrays of the 77 different community areas with the crimes then comparing the length?

Comment: what have you tried to do?  It seems that you could loop over the array of objects and total each of the "areas" or value that are there, and then sort and get the top three values?  Is there more to the data than you are showing - perhaps more of a sample of the data set would be helpful?

Comment: Imagine you need to do that manually on paper. How would you do that if you were asked to find the top 3 criminal areas manually?

Comment: I could iterate over the array, push the crimes into arrays by community area then compare the length of all of them. However, for 77 areas, that doesn't seem efficient. I was wondering if someone had a more efficient way of doing it. As far as what have I tried to do? Nothing. I know how to do it very long hand as I had stated. I'm looking for a _better_ way...

Comment: Lunch time at donut shops

Comment: You can solve such problems in general in `O(n)` time using the [median of medians quickselect variant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians). Sorting based solutions have at least `O(n log n)` time complexity. For only 1000 elements however, sorting might be good enough. Better yet, since you select only the top-3, iterate 3 times over the data and pick the maximum each time in `O(n)`

Comment: There are a [*huge number of duplicates*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+count+object+values). This question should not be answered as it shows no attempt at a solution or to find an existing answer.

Comment: RobG, Most of them are dated 2015 or before. EMCA script updates. If you really feel the need to downvote people's posts, go to that link and downvote each result. I am starting to strongly prefer Reddit over SO because of people like you that have nothing more in life so you complain about the rules on social media and negatively affect someone because of the rules. People like you don't exist as much on reddit. And I'm not sure how you consider "What is an efficient way of doing this other than creating arrays of the 77 different community areas with the crimes then comparing" not attemping.

Comment: @QueSo There does not appear to be an attempt to resolve inquiry by hand, using an algorithm, or a programming language at text of original Question. As to the topic of "efficient", the first step would be to describe what "efficient" means as to requirement, and disclose the benchmarks of what you have tried so far, which are both absent from OP. "efficient" compared to? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pattern for this sort of thing is fairly simple.

Create an object , iterate the array and use the common property of data objects as keys in new object and values will be incremental counts.

Then iterate the new object and compare those counts

```js
var data = [
 {community_area:22},
 {community_area:22},
 {community_area:9},
 {community_area:9},
 {community_area:9},
 {community_area:5},
 {community_area:5},
 {community_area:5},
 {community_area:5},
 {community_area:1},
 {community_area:2},
 {community_area:3},
 
];

var countObj = data.reduce((a,c)=>{
   a[c.community_area] =  (a[c.community_area] || 0 ) + 1;
   return a
},{});

console.log('Community counts', countObj)

var top3 = Object.keys(countObj)
                  .sort((a,b) => countObj[b] - countObj[a] )
                  .slice(0,3)
                  .map(Number);//optional if need number vs string

console.log('Top 3', top3)
```

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this code - it works.  Looks very similar to the other answer.

```js
var testData = [{
  area: 22
}, {
  area: 23
}, {
  area: 17
}, {
  area: 12
}, {
  area: 45
}, {
  area: 12
}, {
  area: 17
}, {
  area: 23
}, {
  area: 34
}, {
  area: 22
}, {
  area: 12
}, {
  area: 45
}, {
  area: 45
}, {
  area: 45
}];

var result = testData.reduce((acc, obj) => {
  if (acc.hasOwnProperty(obj.area)) {
    acc[obj.area]++;
  } else {
    acc[obj.area] = 1;
  };
  return acc;
}, {});

var resultArr = [];
for ( var key in result ) { resultArr.push([key, result[key]]) }

resultArr.sort( (a, b) => b[1] - a[1] );
// now output the first 3 items
for ( var i = 0; i < resultArr.length && i < 3; i++) {
    console.log( `area: ${resultArr[i][0]} =  count ${resultArr[i][1]}`);
    }
```